# Multiple Database Editor Tabs phpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm attempting to move from netbeans to phpstorm and I'm running into an issue with the Database console. I got used to being able to have multiple tabs open for one DB connection.  Is there any way to duplicate this behavior? I don't see an option to open a new console and I can't find anything in the advanced properties of the DB connection listed in the DB panel.

I tried installing the Database Navigator plugin, but it seems to duplicate a lot of functionality.  I like the built in one better, but neither seem to support multiple tabs.

Does anyone have any ideas?  It seems like this should be a fairly common use-case.

I'm on the trial version 6.0.3 and am using the bundled Database Support Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think it is possible with the built in database support.</strike>

**Update**: PhpStorm 9 built in database manager is now able to open multiple consoles for a given connection. Right click on the connection / New / Console.

Using the [Database Navigator plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800?pr=idea) however you can have multiple consoles open for a single connection. First open up a SQL console, then at the top bar close to the Execute Statement button there is a settings dropdown. Open that up and at the bottom of that list you will find Create Console.

[image]